# (13.04) PowerTOP reports lots of usage by USB2.0-CRW, but autosuspend is on

Tags: usb, 13.04, powertop

I used to be able to keep my power usage under 10 watts without WLAN on but now that rarely happens. One reason might be this, reported by PowerTOP all of the time:

```
Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
8.69 W    100.0%                      Device         USB device: USB2.0-CRW (Generic)
```

This is especially odd, because this setting is enabled in tunables (via TLP):

```
   Good          Autosuspend for USB device USB2.0-CRW [Generic]
```

Is there any way I can a) tell exactly which device/driver this is and b) permanently disable it on startup just to make sure it isn't taking any power?

If it helps, here's my lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0292 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0489:e00d Foxconn / Hon Hai Broadcom Bluetooth 2.1 Device
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader
```

Here is the USB section from the output of tlp-stat:

```
+++ USB
tlp usb autosuspend = enabled
tlp usb blacklist   = (not configured)

Bus 001 Device 002 ID 8087:0024 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Intel     Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub (hub)
Bus 002 Device 002 ID 8087:0024 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 002 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 003 ID 5986:0292 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Acer, Inc  (uvcvideo)
Bus 002 Device 003 ID 0489:e00d control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Foxconn / Hon Hai Broadcom Bluetooth 2.1 Device (btusb)
Bus 002 Device 004 ID 0bda:0139 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader (rts5139)
```

Comment: check the config please http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Comment: I looked through /etc/default/tlp and didn't see anything pertaining to the issue.

Comment: on battery ...  sudo tlp-stat

Comment: Alright, I included the USB section (can include other sections if you need)

Comment: do not know ....

Comment: I'm also having the same issue any solutions?

Comment: Same, except mine is `USB3.0-CRW` now.